# Two lecturers, one course, one class

Tags: lecture-teaching-method

This is my first question here, so please correct me if I'm wrong in my way of asking.

My question is suggested directly by the title. In my college institution, for each subject, half of the semester is handled by one lecturer, and the next half by another one. The reasoning is that each lecturer needs to have near equal teaching responsibility. If one lecturer only is applied, there might be some lecturers who have lower or higher workloads than others.

Another reasoning is that this way we can minimize the bias that can happen with just one lecturer. If a lecturer has bias over some students but the other does not, it will somehow even out, rather than just this first lecturer handles the whole semester.

Some negative effects are there of course, but how do you think the negative or positive effects are affecting the learning and teaching experience? My heart says the negatives are just too much.

Comment: What negatives are there in this situation? You haven't mentioned any.

Comment: OK. I have put some in the comments for the answer.

Comment: Your question does not contain a question. Can you please add what you want to know? Note that "what do you think about this?" tends to not be a good question for the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: Double post: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/14269/one-course-subject-one-class-two-lecturers . Please do not post to two SE websites at once; wait for one site to deal with the question and, if those are not satisfactory, post to the other with link to the previous question.

Comment: I would propose to re-phrase the question to clarify the issues involved. E.g. teaching load as a motivation makes little sense to me, but complementary approaches to one topic are of great benefit for the students and we are doing it in many lectures with very good feedback.

Comment: Ok then. I just voted to delete it as I have also posted on other SE website. Thanks for telling me the rules..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens often, lecturer A does micro economics then lecturer B does macro economics.

As students you may prefer A over B but they also like to work towards their strengths...

As long as they cover the material and the assessments are appropriate then 2 lecturers or 1 is not an issue.

You don’t give any negatives but I have mentioned some perceived issues.

Comment: Hmm ok. I thought the negatives are obvious but alright. One example is as you mentioned. For another example, sometimes just for the sake of having 2 lecturers (well, by considering the positives of course), we put aside the matter of lecturer's competency and let a lecturer, who has very less experience on a subject, teach the subject. Sure, this lecturer can learn first, but wouldn't the result be better if he/she has experience, like have taken the subject when in college and got good grade before? Another negative is that since the material per semester is continuous, (cont'd)

Comment: (continuation) a lecturer hopes to see the progress of students understanding. Isn't it harder to do this with two lecturers? Change happens after mid term by the way.

Comment: Don’t put critical information in comments -edit your question with that info - people don’t trawl through comments trying to piece together your question...